# Mesh doesn't follow armature

Tags: mesh, modifiers, rigging, armature, sculpting

Can you guys take a look at the blend file and help me out?The mesh doesn't follow the armature and I tried to make it work all day.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2jzizxan8kilbl/Boxer.blend?dl=0

Thanks[image]

Comment: Please upload files to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Also do not remove and re-add same question. Just edit the first one (give more info, images etc.) and wait for an answer. And please strip down blend file from unnecessary meshes/textures and such. ~90Mb file is to big.

Comment: I can't the file is to big.

Comment: Remove everything beside the mesh and armature and then upload it.

Comment: That's how it is right now.I haven't done the retopology...

Comment: I can't download this file on my internet connection but besides Patdog answer did you parented Armature with the mesh? I've tested (surprisingly for the first time ever) armature with sculpted mesh and it's working, well, not ok, but it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the day arrives that we all have super computers... the meshes used for sculpting are not the ones used for animating. There are too many vertices which makes it cumbersome to rotate around, let alone animate. The automatic weights are not finding a solution - perhaps because of the high vertex count - and though you can manually add weight I don't think this is going to bring much joy.

My suggestion is to retopo a 'lighter' version which will be easier to work with.

Update: In response to Vlads comment below. The greatest concentration of verts are in the face. Selecting the face and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to separate it from the rest of the body. The headless body accepts the automatic bone weights and can be deformed by the armature. The obvious problem are the gaps that will form between the two objects.

It is always easier to talk after the fact but... finding a pose with a simpler mesh, earlier in the process, would have saved a lot of trouble.

Comment: I just want to pose it and render it out as a image.Do you know a easier way to pose it than doing retopology and armature?

Comment: updated a suggestion above

Comment: I will try it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks man you made my day..it worked!https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR8IE.png